# Putnam and Beyond (Methods of proof) Problem 20

Tags: proof-verification, contest-math

Here is the problem as stated in "Putnam and Beyond":

> Given a sequence of integers $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ whose sum is 1, prove that exactly one of the cyclic shifts
>
> $x_1,x_2,..., x_n ; x_2,...,x_n,x_1; ....; x_n,x_1,...,x_{n-1}$
>
> has all of its partial sums positive.( By a partial sum we mean the sum of the first $k$ terms, $k\leq n$.

The proof is expected to be inductive, but ( this being my reason for making this query) I have come up with a different "algorithmic" approach. Below I will state my idea and I would be very grateful if you could tell me where I have gone wrong or missed a step, if that is the case.

We start of with the sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and perform shifts according to the following  scheme.

Our first step will be to group the terms into two sequences $(x_1),(x_2,...,x_n)$. As it is impossible for all terms to be negative or zero, either **(i)** $x_1 >0$ or **(ii)** $x_2+...+x_n>0$. If **(i)** then leave the sequence unchanged and if **(ii)** perform a single shift to obtain $(x_2,...,x_n),(x_1)$. In the first case we have a sequence with positive partial sums for $k=1$ and $k=n$ and in the second case our sequence has positive partial sums for $k=n-1$ and $k=n$.

We wish to improve on this and continue to group the terms once again as follows for **(i)** $(x_1,x_2),(x_3,...,x_n)$. Again either (i)' $x_1+x_2>0$ or (ii)' $x_3+...+x_n>0$. In the case of (i)' leave the sequence unchanged and in the case of (ii)' perform one shift to obtain $(x_3,...,x_n), (x_1,x_2)$. Our new sequences now positive partial sums for $k=1,2$ and $k=n$ in case of (i)' and positive partial sums for $k=n-2,n-1$ and $k=n$. Continuing in this manner we can improve the number of positive partial sums by 1 at each iteration.

Now making improvements on the sequence in case **(ii)**, $(x_2,...,x_n),(x_1)$. 
We group as we did our original sequence: $(x_2),(x_3,...,x_n,x_1)$. As before we ask whether $(x_2)>0$. If $(x_2)>0$ then leave the sequence unchanged, else perform a single shift to obtain $(x_3,....,x_n,x_1,x_2)$. Either way we have improved on the number of positive partial sums.

Continue in this manner until all partial sums $k\leq n$ are positive.

Reading my above argument I am aware that it is very long and very messy, not for the lack of trying. I hope that nevertheless the idea is understood. Thank You for any help!

(P.S. Please do not post the textbook solution, I am aware of it)

Comment: I think you should write the algorithm more clearly.  Explain what the algorithm checks, and does in numbered steps.  Your idea may work, but if you were in a competition, a solution like this will not receive a lot of points (I am sorry that this sounds harsh, but as a person who participated in Putnam, I know what to expect).  At this point, your algorithm seems to branch into multiple, perhaps too many, cases, and this seems a bit worrisome to me.  And you still have not proven whether the end result is the only possible circular shift that has the required property.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you very much  for you advice and don't worry about being to harsh. Criticism is what I asked for afterall! I will try and write my idea out more clearly as you suggested. P.S. I am not a putnam contestant, not even an undergraduate... just here for the fun :).

Comment: @Batominovski Maybe I can clarify: The general idea I had in mind was to start of with any sequence and group of "the first few" terms. If their sum were negative I would perform a shift, putting these terms to the end of the sequence, so that the first few terms gave a positive partial sum. On the other hand if their sum were positive I would leave the sequence and make the group larger until it had a negative sum. So at the start I would only look at one term, then at two, and so on and so on. I will try to write this properly though in a new post later. Thank you again for you advice!

Comment: I partially understand your idea.  My problem is to see how it works when you add a third element (you will deal with $x_3$ next, I guess) to what is already known (i.e. $x_1$ and $x_2$).  It is unclear to me how the procedure at this step will be.